# Can we improve redundancy theorem of Boolean Algebra?

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

By redundancy theorem of Boolean Algebra, we have

$xy+\bar{x}z+yz=xy+\bar{x}z$.

My problem is, can we further simply the term in the right side of the above expression? That is, $xy+\bar{x}z=y+z$? Is the last expression true?

Comment: In that last expression, take $z=x$. It follows $xy=x+y$. I think it is clear to you that this is not true.